# Dagger2 Error at inject in a class who injects

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, mvp

I'm trying to `inject` in my `presenter` an `interactor` but gives me an error, at seems I can't inject in a class who injects to another:

```
error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion is bound multiple times:
@Provides com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion com.example.calculadora.Inject.InteractorModule.provideDiv()
@Provides com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion com.example.calculadora.Inject.InteractorModule.provideMult()
@Provides com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion com.example.calculadora.Inject.InteractorModule.provideResta()
@Provides com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion com.example.calculadora.Inject.InteractorModule.provideSuma()
com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion is injected at
com.example.calculadora.Domain.PresenterImpl.operacion
com.example.calculadora.Domain.PresenterImpl is injected at
com.example.calculadora.Inject.InteractorComponent.inject(com.example.calculadora.Domain.PresenterImpl)
```

This is my `InteractorModule` who provides me a 4 classes depending which I want to use and where seems is the problem:

```
@Module
public class InteractorModule {
    @Provides
    public Operacion provideSuma() {
        return new InteractorSuma();
    }

    @Provides
    public Operacion provideResta() {
        return new InteractorResta();
    }

    @Provides
    public Operacion provideDiv() {
        return new InteractorDivision();
    }

    @Provides
    public Operacion provideMult() {
        return new InteractorMultiplicacion();
    }
}
```

I want to inject here instead of init the new items:

```
@Override
public void setCalculo() {
    Operacion operacion = null;
    String[] operandos = vista.getOperandos();
    Operando operando1 = new Operando(Integer.parseInt(operandos[0]));
    Operando operando2 = new Operando(Integer.parseInt(operandos[1]));


    switch (tipoOperacion) {
        case SUMA:
            operacion = new InteractorSuma(operando1, operando2);
            break;
        case RESTA:
            operacion = new InteractorResta(operando1, operando2);
            break;
        case MULT:
            operacion = new InteractorMultiplicacion(operando1, operando2);
            break;
        case DIV:
            operacion = new InteractorDivision(operando1, operando2);
            break;
    }

    operacion.calcular();
    vista.mostrarResultado(String.valueOf(operacion.getResultado().getValor()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate one-other with the `@Named("someName")` annotation, or you could just do what @Derek says. My approach:

```
@Provides
@Named("someName1")
    public Operacion provideSuma() {
        return new InteractorSuma();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("someName2")
    public Operacion provideResta() {
        return new InteractorResta();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("someName3")
    public Operacion provideDiv() {
        return new InteractorDivision();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("someName4")
    public Operacion provideMult() {
        return new InteractorMultiplicacion();
    }
```

Otherwise dagger doesn't know which one to return where.

Call the `@Named` when injecting also.

Comment: Gives me and error:  `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

Comment: you should also use the `@Named` when calling the dependency from the component

Comment: And how I should injected in my case? I put the code in the question.

Comment: @Inject
    Presenter(@Named("someName1") Operacion operacion) { }

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of situation is where Dagger2 `Qualifiers` are build for.

**1.- Create your qualifiers:**

```
@Qualifier
public @interface OperacionSuma {}
@Qualifier
public @interface OperacionResta {}
@Qualifier
public @interface OperacionDiv {}
@Qualifier
public @interface OperacionMult {}
```

**2.- Set qualifiers in your providers methods:**

```
@Module
public class InteractorModule {
    @Provides
    @OperacionSuma
    public Operacion provideSuma() {
        return new InteractorSuma();
    }

    @Provides
    @OperacionResta
    public Operacion provideResta() {
        return new InteractorResta();
    }

    @Provides
    @OperacionDiv
    public Operacion provideDiv() {
        return new InteractorDivision();
    }

    @Provides
    @OperacionMult
    public Operacion provideMult() {
        return new InteractorMultiplicacion();
    }
}
```

**3.- Specify what kind of "operation" do you want to inject in your presenter:**

```
class Presenter {

    @Inject
    Presenter(@OperacionSuma Operacion operacion) { }

    @Inject
    Presenter(@OperacionResta Operacion operacion) { }

    @Inject
    Presenter(@OperacionDiv Operacion operacion) { }

    @Inject
    Presenter(@OperacionMult Operacion operacion) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since dagger looks for the return type, not a name that given to the function you should take care of it. However, Dagger2 provides a solution to such problems. Using @Named annotation.

> Sometimes the type alone is insufficient to identify a dependency. For example, if you need a Refrofit instance with GsonConverterFactory and another one ScalarConverterFactory you will end up with 2 provide methods that have the same return type: Retrofit. In this case, you can use @Named annotation to differentiate two Retrofit instances

[image]

Now you can use it like following

[image]

Coming to your case

```
@Module
public class InteractorModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("InteractorSuma")
    public Operacion provideSuma() {
        return new InteractorSuma();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("InteractorResta")
    public Operacion provideResta() {
        return new InteractorResta();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("InteractorDivision")
    public Operacion provideDiv() {
        return new InteractorDivision();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("InteractorMultiplicacion")
    public Operacion provideMult() {
        return new InteractorMultiplicacion();
    }
}
```

[Here is](https://medium.com/@muratkaraoz/dagger2-cheat-sheet-1-8afd891f9cd5) the full example of how to use `@Named` annotation

Let me know if you have still a problem

Answer (score 0):

Return the instance of Child class, not parent class.

```
@Module
public class InteractorModule {
    @Provides
    public InteractorSuma provideSuma() {
        return new InteractorSuma();
    }

    @Provides
    public InteractorResta provideResta() {
        return new InteractorResta();
    }

    @Provides
    public InteractorDivision provideDiv() {
        return new InteractorDivision();
    }

    @Provides
    public InteractorMultiplicacion provideMult() {
        return new InteractorMultiplicacion();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I do the same with my `Presenter` to injected in my `View` and works fine. I post the code of my `Presenter`. I put the code below:

Comment: `@Module
public class PresenterModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Presenter providePresenter() {
        return new PresenterImpl();
    }
}`

Comment: This is if you want to inject instance of same class.

Comment: Gives me the error: `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.calculadora.Data.Interactor.Operacion cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

Comment: Also change the `@Inject` variable type to the child class instead of Parent. This error is because you have left them as  `Operacion `